# How to query all data in a CGI environment?

Tags: perl

I need to know the CGI variables in my script. I know I can use

```
$query->param()
```

to get CGI parameters, but how can I get module paths and the version of Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you question is really vague..

to get the complete environment and all installed modules use this:

```
#!"\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;        
use File::Find ;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

# use sneaky cgi direct printing ;)
$|=1 ;

# define subs
sub permodules;

# print header
print header;
print start_html("Environment");

# get perl version
print `perl -v`;

# get env vars
foreach (sort keys %ENV) {
    print $ENV{$_};
}

# get inc vars
print @INC;
foreach my $path (@INC) {
    next if ($path =~ /^\./) ;
    find(\&perlmodules,$path) ;
}

# get mods
my (@mods,%mods);
@mods=sort {lc($a) cmp lc($b)} keys %mods;
my $amount=int($#mods/3+.9999) ;
for (my $mod=0 ; $mod<$amount ; $mod++)  {
    print $mods[$mod] . "-" . $mods[$mod+1*$amount] . "-" . $mods[$mod+2*$amount] ;
}

sub perlmodules {   

    if ($File::Find::name =~ /\.pm$/){      
        open(MODFILE,$File::Find::name) || return;      
        while(<MODFILE>){           
            if (/^ *package +(\S+);/) {             
                $mods{$1}=1 ;   
                last;
            }
        }
        close(MODFILE) ;
    }
}

# end
print end_html;
```

adapt the print statements to fit your needs.

Comment: That doesn't compile. (Well, unless you forgo using `use strict;`, but that's just silly.)

Comment: @ikegame that was only a sharp shoot and untested. some typo not more.. now it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everything is stored in the `%ENV` hash. [Here's a good example of how to display them](http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch3/text.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

print header;
print start_html("Environment");

foreach my $key (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
    print "$key = $ENV{$key}<br>\n";
}

print end_html;
```

EDIT: [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21690017/1454048) is more comprehensive, and will return module information as well.

Comment: thank you! +1 from me because of a very solid answer. my could be a lil unclear for beginners maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs they are very good.

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

They cover almost everything you'll run into.

%ENV and such

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES

Answer (score 1):

When you "use" a module (i.e., "use File::Find;") Perl loads the first occurrence of that module that it finds in the @INC and sticks it into %INC.  For example, if you're looking to find which version of File::Find you're using, you can simply print the corresponding entry from %INC.

The command will look like this:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'print $INC{"File/Find.pm"} . "\n";'
```

Which prints this on my mac:

```
/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/lib/File/Find.pm
```